# How do I precache files on a perfoce proxy server in order to obtain some decent speed?

Tags: caching, perforce, synchronization

Perforce proxy does cache files only when a user does sync them so if you are the single user of a perforce proxy that is syncing some locations you will gain almost nothing from it.

The question is how to make perforce cache the files for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for this is to create a scheduled task/crontab that will simulate a sync for you.

You will have to create a branchspec for this client,

```
export P4CLIENT=prefetch
p4 -Zproxyload sync //depot/main/...
```

This command will not copy the files to your client, it will only tell the proxy to cache them.